# How can I get index path of cell on switch change event in section based table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, xcode6

I have custom cell having switch in few cells at right side. what I want is to store value of specific cell on switch change event. Table view has number sections so I can't set tag for switch because I need section as well as row to obtain index path.

Any suggestion any alternative but I have to use UISwitch in section based table view.

Thanks

Comment: Is it ok if you get that cell object on UISwitch value changes selecter ?

Comment: Yes, in UI switch state get changed but I can't decide which switch stat has been changed.

Comment: see my answer it may be halp

Comment: There are two things you need to deal with. 1) Your cell is a view onto and controller for a piece of your overall data. It needs to contain a reference for that data. 2) You need a handler for when that data is changed. You can do this in the cell or better do it in a central place like the table view. See my answer which shows how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your custom cell add properties which help you identify the information the cell represents. Index path, indexes for your data model etc...

Then add a block property to the cell which you can call to tell a UITableView or any other piece of code when a cell switch changes. e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) void (^onSwitchChange)(UITableViewCell *cell);
```

Inside your custom cell code, add an action handler for the UISwitch. When it fires, call self.onSwitchChange(self) which will notify the code which registered an onSwitchChange block that a switch has changed and on which cell.

In your table view when you create the cell, set the onSwitchChange block as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  <snip>

  YourUITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:yourCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.onSwitchChange=^(UITableViewCell *cellAffected){
    // Add code to deal with the swicth switch using properties of cellAffected
    ... Your handler code here ...
  }];

  <snip>
}
```

This lets you handle all the changes in the table view controller. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Jageen works. I had to find out which superview the cell is, mine was one more level higher.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview].superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"Section %ld Row : %ld",(long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.row); // print row section and index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still create tags even if you have sections if you have some idea of about max rows in a largest section. For example if you think there will be 1000 rows in a section then you can create tag using following formula.

```
tag = section * 1000 + row;
```

later in your IBAction of switch you can find out the indexpath (section and row) using following:

```
section = tag/1000;
row = tag%1000;
```

If you have no idea of how many rows your section will have you can find out the cell using `sender.superview.superview` (be careful if have added any other views in hierarchy).

Rory McKinnel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28320038/1407906) is still the cleanest solution for your problem.