# How do I get an event message from UITextField in a custom table cell to the table cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm sure this is a very noddy question, but I just can't get anything useful from the manuals.

I've a `UITextField` embedded in a custom `UITableViewCell`. If I use a delegate for the `UITextView` - it just gives me the `UITextView`.

If I link the event to the `ParerentViewController`, it just gives me the ID of the `UITextView`.

What I want to do is handle the event at the `UITableViewCell` level. Can I get the events from this text control to feed to the parent, and handle them at the parent level.

I don't seem to even be able to find the parent cell from the `UITextField` that the handler gives me. How do I find out which cell within the table the `UITextField` is in when I'm trying to process the events.

I have to be missing something obvious, as I've done this in earlier (pre storyboard) versions, and I'm sure it wasn't this difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Answered a similar question the other day. See the accepted answer.

[How can I get index path of cell on switch change event in section based table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319611/how-can-i-get-index-path-of-cell-on-switch-change-event-in-section-based-table-v/28320038#28320038)

This will let you handle the text changes in the cell and pass them on to the table view. In your case its a UITextView and not a UISwitch.

Add properties to the cell for anything you will need inside the block code when it is called.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and implement the `textField` delegates inside the subclass. The code is lengthy but if you want I can post it when I get time.