# Updating data after modal segue completed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How can I update data after modal segue has been dismissed? As I think the best way is using notifications, but I don't know how to set up notification in main view after modal segue has been closed.

E.g. I have "Login" modal view, when user clicks "Done" modal view is dismissed, main view reads new data from NSUserDefaults and displays new data.

```
@IBAction func doneClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    settings.synchronize()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unwind segues if you are using storyboard. Then you just use `segue.sourceViewController` and fetch the data that you need from the - now dismissed - modal viewcontroller. In your case, you don't even need any data from the modal viewcontroller, so just put whatever you want in the unwindSegue IBAction-method.

A guide:
http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/

Answer (score 0):

Use the completion handler you set to nil in `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated`

Instead of nil, put in a completion handler with the code you want to run once it has completed dismissing.

An alternative, and possibly better option, is to not dismiss the controller from itself but from the controller which presented it.

Add a block property to the controller called `onDone` which can be registered by the controller doing the presenting. In your button action simply call this `onDone` block. The controller which presented the controller will be notified, can call `dismissViewController` and use the completion to tidy things up.

This is a better approach since it caters for the controller with the button being raised in a number of ways: push, modal or in a popover on iPad. Having the presenter also do the dismiss makes it easier to handle these different options since the presenter knows how it presented the controller.

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319611/how-can-i-get-index-path-of-cell-on-switch-change-event-in-section-based-table-v/28320038#28320038.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger notification when view disappears from screen

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loginNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Or

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
```

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loginNotification" object:nil];

```
}];
```

Comment: This is... hacky.. to say the least. EDIT AFTER YOUR EDIT: The first option that is.