# Change another cell in dynamic prototype UITableView when a switch in one cell change

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I used to use static `UITableView` but the table is too long and overflow the memory.

I switched a dynamic prototype `UITableView` with 1 type of cell, which has an `UISwitch` in it.

One of the cell, when turning on the switch, will turn off the switch of another cell. These cells have fixed index.

The `IBAction` method is in my `UITableViewCell` subclass and I don't want to add the `UITableView` as a property in my `UITableViewCell`.
How do I achieve the above effect?

I'm planing to use an `id` or similar to distinguish between the cells as each cell's switch has different effects, that doesn't solve the above requirement.

Thanks,

Comment: is the cell that is to be changed fixed or it could be any random cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a block property to your cell which you can use to notify your controller of changes in the switch. See my answer below to a question on this:

[How can I get index path of cell on switch change event in section based table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319611/how-can-i-get-index-path-of-cell-on-switch-change-event-in-section-based-table-v/28320038#28320038)

All your logic can now be implemented in the view controller.

You are best to create a data model in the view controller which the cells simply provide views and controls onto. When you flick one switch and the block fires, update the data model and simply reload the table. Any cells affected will show the new data model positions for their switches. Avoid using one cell to adjust another. Just update the model and reload the cells.

Comment: The answer in the link is what I need. Regarding your comment about model. How does the model notify the view to reload? I don't want the model to have the knowledge of the view

Comment: Sorry, probably bad wording. The data model is just for holding the current state of everything. Your view controller and cells are views and controls onto that data. So you use the blocks fired by the buttons etc to notify the view controller which updates the data model. It is in the same code that you reload the table, not the data model code. So logic is block is provided by view controller to cells, cells execute blocks on activity, code in blocks updates the data model and if needed reloads the table. As all the cells reflect the data model, everything updates automatically on reload.